# Visual Studio does not find include files, but paths are correct

Tags: visual-studio, include, header-files

For my project, I am using Visual Studio 2015. I have added to my include path the folder `$(ProjectDir)Source`. In details view of `Include Directories`, in the list below with `Evaluated value`, the correct path is listed. When I copy this path using `#include "path/file"`, it finds the file. Or via `Start` > `Run`, it opens the path.

In my project I have a `.cpp` file which includes the file like usual:
`#include <file>`.

Still, I am receiving the error: `Cannot open include file 'file.h' No such file or directory`. Error `C1083`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied an existing solution which had similar includes and adjusted them accordingly. It works now.